# Adding users from trusted Active Directory Domain to TFS

Tags: tfs, active-directory

We are in the process of migrating users from one domain to another due to a company merger. Our TFS 2015 environment was set up under the Company1 active directory domain, and Company2 is now a trusted domain.

In TFS, I am trying to add users from Company2 via the "Add users and groups" dialog found on the Settings | Security screen.  However, I am (oddly, and somewhat suspiciously) only able to see three Company2\username accounts using the auto-complete funcitonality, and I do not see any others when I enter Company2\realname and attempt to search.  I *am* able to add any users from Company1.

Are there jobs of some kind that need to run to allow these accounts to be visible?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and turning it back on again? (W.A.G., but it might be caching)

Comment: Did you also move the TFS from company1 Domain to company2 Domain, or just leave TFS in company1 Domain?

Answer (score 1):

If you have also moved TFS server from domain of company1 to company2. For TFS join to its new domain, you need to **restart the computer** for the domain change to take effect.

If you didn't change the TFS server domain. You could first create a new user in Domain 2  to see if it could be added to TFS. This maybe AD sync issue. More detials please take a look at this blog： [Force TFS to sync with Active Directory](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/) & [Identity Synchronization in Team Foundation Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vasu_sankaran/2010/06/07/identity-synchronization-in-team-foundation-server-2010/)